# Can't create covered query with nulls in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, null

Why does MongoDB (version 4.2.8) handle queries with and without null differently?

Sample:

```
    db.b.insertMany([
     {c:"a", },
     {c:"a", },
     {c:"a", n:null},
    {c:"a", n:1},
    {c:"a", n:10},
    {c:"a", n:5},
    {c:"a", n:1},
    {c:"a", n:12},
    {c:"b", n:12},
]);
db.b.createIndex({"n": 1, "c": 1});
```

Then if I call

```
db.b.find({c: "a", n: {$in:[10, 12]}}, {_id: 0, n:1,c:1}).explain("allPlansExecution")
```

the query is fully covered.
But, the query

```
db.b.find({c: "a", n: {$in:[null, 12]}}, {_id: 0, n:1,c:1}).explain("allPlansExecution")
```

isn't covered, and MongoDB fetches all found documents.

It looks like a bug in MongoDB.

Comment: Removed my answer, as it is not correct. Maybe this could be related https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/multikey-index-bounds/, it's a long article though.

Comment: I read it before :) Nothing new